# How to resolve errors installing pybullet

Tags: python, pip, pybullet

I am attempting to install pybullet (`pip install pybullet`) inside my python virtual environment, but it always fails. I get the following error: ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybullet

I have created a virtual environment with `python3 -m venv env`, and installed a few common libraries using pip (ex. `pip install numpy`) without issue. I then try to install pybullet with `pip install pybullet`, and that fails (I have tried both pip and pip3, no difference). pip successfully collects the tar.gz file (either collects it anew or uses the cached one from previous attempts, the result is the same), and then begins the following procedure:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pybullet 
    Building wheel for pybullet (setup.py) ... error
```

It prints 'error' there after a few seconds of working, and then proceeds to dump a massive error message (>10000 lines, the limit of my terminal history currently). The last part of the error message seems fairly descriptive and useful:

```
    ...
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybullet
    Running setup.py clean for pybullet
Failed to build pybullet
ERROR: could not build wheels for pybullet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

But unfortunately I have been unable to find a solution to this. I did some looking around and on an old forum somebody suggested just cloning the repository and building it locally, which I tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3.git
cd bullet3
setup.py build
setup.py install
```

But this also did not work. It printed out many lines of warnings about things like unused variables in the code, but in the end I was still not able to use pybullet.

Has anybody encountered this, or does anybody know why this is happening?

My computer runs Ubuntu Linux OS. I've included some other possibly relevant details below.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.19.0-46-generic 22.04.1-Ubuntu GNU/Linux
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
$ pip --version
pip 23.1.2
```

Comment: The current version `pybullet` 3.2.5 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/3.2.5/#files) for Linux on x64 for Pythons up to Python 3.9. Try Python 3.9. Please show the full text of the error; redirect output to a file, [edit] and insert it into the question; or publish at some hosting and put here an URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only issue was my Python version. I switched to Python 3.9.17 for my virtual environment and it install without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The current version pybullet 3.2.5 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/3.2.5/#files) for Linux on x64 for Pythons up to Python 3.9. Use Python 3.9.