# Facing issues installing pybullet

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, robotics, openai-gym, bulletphysics

I am trying to install pybullet 3.2.6 on Python 3.9.12 on Windows 11  64 bit operating system on a Jupyter notebook using the command:

```
!pip install pybullet>=3.2.6
```

But this leads to a long error message ending with:

```
s.stable_baselines', 'pybullet_envs.agents.ppo', 'pybullet_envs.agents.tools', 'pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.env', 'pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.gym_env', 'pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.learning', 'pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.learning.nets', 'pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.learning.solvers', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.actuatornet', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.robots', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.vision', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents.baseline_controller', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents.ppo', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents.scripts', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents.tools', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.agents.trajectory_generator', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs.env_randomizers', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.env_wrappers', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.evaluation', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.examples', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.scenes', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.sensors', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.tasks', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.envs_v2.utilities', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.robots.safety', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.robots.utilities', 'pybullet_envs.minitaur.robots.safety.python', 'pybullet_robots.laikago', 'pybullet_robots.panda', 'pybullet_robots.xarm', 'pybullet_utils.examples']
  -----
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybullet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pybullet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616039/how-to-resolve-errors-installing-pybullet) but the answer recommends using Python 3.9 which I am already using.

Is this due to a compatibility issue? Is pybullet 3.2.6 compatible with Python 3.9.12? I also tried pybullet 3.2.5 but that too failed. How do you resolve this error?

Comment: I doubt that this will help for here because you seem to have either conflict with dependencies and versions for compatibility with pybullet, or the environment isn't quite set up right, but you'll have a better experience in Jupyter going forward if you are following current best practices and so I share this....For running install commands in modern Jupyter you should be using the magic variation of the install commands. For here that would be `%pip install ...`. The exclamation point used in conjunction with install commands can lead to unexpected issues and so in 2019 the magic ...

Comment: <continued> variations of the install commands were added that **importantly insure the installation occurs in the environment where the Python kernel is running that is underlying the running `.ipynb` file**. See more about the magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). More at the top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why ...

Comment: <continued> using the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands run in a notebook can lead to problems. You can use that a gauge for more current advice for working with Jupyter.

Comment: As for the issue here with pybullet, the page you reference in your post ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616039/how-to-resolve-errors-installing-pybullet)) is very clear that the operating system that seems to be the one meant to be used with this library and a pip install is linux. See [the requirements](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3?tab=readme-ov-file#requirements-for-bullet-physics-c) for windows. I think if you read through [here](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues?q=is%3Aissue+windows+is%3Aopen) you'll see you have more to do then just run pip.