# How can I install packages in Jupyterlab online?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupyterlab online (https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab) and can't install a package. I did a lot search and people says it can be done by `!pip install PACKAGE`. However, I got this error when run `!pip install requests` or any packages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install requests')

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2629, in InteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
   2624     raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
   2626 # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because
   2627 # a non-None value would trigger :func:`sys.displayhook` calls.
   2628 # Instead, we store the exit_code in user_ns.
-> 2629 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py:129, in ProcessHandler.system(self, cmd)
    125 enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING
    127 # Patterns to match on the output, for pexpect.  We read input and
    128 # allow either a short timeout or EOF
--> 129 patterns = [pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF]
    130 # the index of the EOF pattern in the list.
    131 # even though we know it's 1, this call means we don't have to worry if
    132 # we change the above list, and forget to change this value:
    133 EOF_index = patterns.index(pexpect.EOF)

AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'
```

The error `Background processes not supported` seems mean it can't install any pakcage. Is it true? How can I make it run in frontground?

what is the right way to install an external package?

Comment: "Background processes not supported." Likely this instance doesn't support shell commands.

Comment: yep, I read this error. What is the right way to install a package? or does it mean it doesn't support install?

Comment: You may need a different instance type. Remember you can run this locally, and there are many other options for running it, including Google Cloud and AWS, among *many* others. Free notebooks, at least outside of trial accounts, are usually quite restricted. This may be a case of "We can't have nice things" because of crypto scammers, etc. always looking to run their mining garbage on anything and everything they can.

Comment: I am using the online platform. so you suggest to use a different one?

Comment: You are using the trial one. Of course you can't do anything other than basic stuff

Comment: ok thanks. I will use the local one.

Comment: I'd argue you are overemphasizing the limitations, @drum. While it can do a lot JupyterLite is indeed more limited to what works in the pyopdide-based kernel. The requests package is one of those that isn't supported by pyodide because of the networking. Joey Yi Zhao, you can still use online Jupyter but use a full python kernel served kernel using a remote, temporary computer served by MyBinder.org. For example, you can go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) in your browser and click 'launch binder'. The session will come up in ...

Comment: <continued> a minute or so. That is running on a remote computer. You'll note the kernel is different than the pyodide one you saw in JupyterLite. Because this is a **temporary session** on a remote computer, if you make anything useful, be sure to download it immediately back to your local system so you can use it again. Finally, you bring up installing packages while in a running `.ipynb` file. You should univerally using the magic install commands. They even work in JupyterLite, as long as the package can be installed in that system. For example `%pip install rich` would install the ...

Comment: <continued> [rich package](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) and that will work in JupyterLite. If you launched the session from https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements (or **generally** any other 'launch binder' badge), you can run `%pip install requests` in a running `.ipynb` file with the typical, full Python kernel. When it completes successfully, restart the kernel and you can use the package. Anything suggesting you use an exclamation point with install commands is outdated and you can use that as a gauge to tell if you are following advice from those keeping current with ...

Comment: <cotninued> Jupyter best practices. See the first three of my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714509/facing-issues-installing-pybullet#comment137014558_77714509) for more on the magic install commands with links to the resources. (You'd use `%conda install` if you choose to use Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager and only resort to `%pip install` when there's no conda recipe for that package.)

Comment: Finally, I'd point out you want to be careful and clear when talking about and looking for help. For example, your title, phrase 'I am using Jupyterlab online'  in the first line of your text, and then comment of 'I am using the online platform' **are all inexact**. You are using the JupyterLab interface with JupyterLite or the JupyterLab interface with the Pyodide kernel. As you hopefully have now seen by launching a session from where I suggest, you can use JupyterLab online with a full Python kernel. And that would meet the qualifications of what you said without being the ...

Comment: <continued> same as what you were talking about as 'online JupyterLab'. Thankfully you included the link in your post so it was somewhat clear. But when trying to find help it will be good to use the right terms for searching.

Comment: But yeah, this is true that the full binder instances are not available on that site because of users who mined crypto - we can't have nice things for free if other's don't play nice and use up all resources.